# error 400 Bad Request en una petición GET a una api

Tags: c#, api, .net

Hola construi una api pero al momento de consumir la api y consultar lo que tiene por metodo GET me sale el error 400 bad request seguido del siguiente mensaje The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.

este es mi controlador:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ICompanyService _companyService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public CompanyController(ICompanyService companyService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _companyService = companyService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanies()
    {
        var companies = await _companyService.GetCompanies();
        var companyDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(companies);
        var response = new ApiResponse<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(companyDto);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanie(int id)
    {
        var company = await _companyService.GetCompanie(id);
        var companyDto = _mapper.Map<CompanyDto>(company);
        var response = new ApiResponse<CompanyDto>(companyDto);
        return Ok(response);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(CompanyDto companyDto)
    {
        var company = _mapper.Map<Company>(companyDto);
        await _companyService.InsertCompany(company);
        companyDto = _mapper.Map<CompanyDto>(company);
        var response = new ApiResponse<CompanyDto>(companyDto);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put(int id, CompanyDto companyDto)
    {
        var company = _mapper.Map<Company>(companyDto);
        company.IdCompany = id;

        
        var result = await _companyService.UpdateCompany(company);
        var response = new ApiResponse<bool>(result);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var result = await _companyService.DeleteCompany(id);
        var response = new ApiResponse<bool>(result);
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

Al compilar mi api no me muestra ningún error así tengo mi repositorio ya revise y parece que todo esta bien todo esta heredando correctamente por lo que a un no entiendo que puede estar pasando

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompanies()
    {
        var company = await _context.Company.ToListAsync();
        return company;
    }
    public async Task<Company> GetCompanie(int id)
    {
        var company = await _context.Company.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.IdCompany == id);
        return company;
    }
    public async Task InsertCompany(Company company)
    {
        _context.Company.Add(company);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateCompany(Company company)
    {
        var currentCompany = await GetCompanie(company.IdCompany);
        currentCompany.RegistrationDate = currentCompany.RegistrationDate;


        int rows = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return rows > 0;
    }
    public async Task<bool> DeleteCompany(int id)
    {
        var currentCompany = await GetCompanie(id);
        _context.Company.Remove(currentCompany);

        int rows = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return rows > 0;
    }
```

La prueba la estoy haciendo desde el postman he probado quitar el https cambiar de puerto, eliminar cache, confirmar url, probar en navegadores diferentes y a un asi no logro resolver el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la imagen de mi postman. voy adjuntar la imagen de swagger que es algo que tambien estoy utilizando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que revisar toda la configuración que estas usando en postman para el consimo de la api. En soluciones orientadas a serviciós el problema no es siemprr delnservicio, sino de como se consume

Comment: A que endpoint de tu API estas realizando el request? Podrías adjuntar una imagen de postman?

Comment: estoy revisando y parece que todo esta bien configurado en postman @MauricioOrtega

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera agregue la imagen tanto de postman como swagger las peticiones son get no se que problema podria hacer, el endpoint asi lo tengo app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz primero, si estas levantando en local tu proyecto, debes quitar el https, y dejar solo http. Por lo menos no veo nada raro en tu request, y si especificas en tu `HttpGet` una ruta? Por ejemplo `[HttpGet('companies')]`, y cuando realices la peticion en Postman, colocas `http://localhost.../company/companies`

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera ya verifique todo lo que me comentaste de igual manera sigue el mismo error.

Comment: Ouch! Verifique cada cosa que se me ocurrió de tu código y tu Request y no le veo nada malo :( Si llegas a solucionarlo, no dudes en compartir la respuesta.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera de acuerdo ando en ello.

Comment: Hola Eduardo puedes ponerle un punto de quiebre y decirme en que capa se cae si en el controller o el service o el repository, quizas es el automapper.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo unas sugerencias que puedes manejar y puede que den con tu solución.

1. Una el atributo Route para indicarle al método su nombre especifico de api (aplica para todos los métodos de la api, ya sea GET, POST, PUT o DELETE).
2. (Sugerencia), Incluye en tu código los bloques de Try Catch, para que puedas tener una referencia directa con los errores que se podrían generar en tu código y así lo retornas con el BadRequest.
3. No enviar el atributo en el atributo [HttpGet]. Si la api tiene atributos, agrégaselos junto al nombre del método 'Método/{atributo}', dentro del atributo Route. En caso de tener mas atributos: 'Método/{atributo}/{atributo2}/{etc}'

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetCompanies")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanies()
{
    try 
    {
        var companies = await _companyService.GetCompanies();
        var companyDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(companies);
        var response = new ApiResponse<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(companyDto);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetCompanie/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanie(int id)
{
    try 
    {
        var company = await _companyService.GetCompanie(id);
        var companyDto = _mapper.Map<CompanyDto>(company);
        var response = new ApiResponse<CompanyDto>(companyDto);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Espero esto te sea de ayuda.